# How to perform a monte carlo simulation on a honeycomb lattice with first, second and third nearest neighbor interactions?

Tags: python, monte-carlo

I want to perform monte carlo simulation on a honeycomb lattice. Can someone please help me on how to define a matrix for these interactions and how many terms there will be while sampling the configuration? A honeycomb lattice has 3 first nearest-neighbors, 6 second nearest-neighbors and 3 third nearest-neighbors.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp. What exactly are you trying to integrage via monte carlo? What kind of interaction are you trying to express via the matrix you mention? If you provide us with some sketches or the mathematical problem you are facing this community will have an easier time helping you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to perform monte carlo simulation of an Ising honeycomb lattice and how to write energy term. For a sqaure lattice it is easier. By matrix I meant how to define first, second and third nearest neighbour. I might be wrong in saying matrix. Can we choose neighbours using distance cut-off?